# how to send with retrofit2 parsing jsonObject to string in Android?

Tags: android

I wanna send data that is content-type : application/json.  when I send not creating data class file but only parsing JSONObject to String, I got incorrect string like this 
`{\"mobile\":\"01011111111\"}"` I want to send without this `\`. how can I remove that?

here is my code

```
   override fun checkSMS(mobile: String): Call<NetworkResult> {
        val jsonObject = JSONObject()
        try {
            jsonObject.put("mobile", mobile)
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        showLog("jsonObject : "+jsonObject)
        return service.checkSMS(jsonObject.toString())
    }
```

```
    @POST("smsCheck")
    fun checkSMS(
        @Body params: String
    ) :Call<NetworkResult>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [**`accumulate`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#accumulate(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))

```
 val jsonObject = JSONObject()
 jsonObject.accumulate("mobile",mobile)
```

Your **`POST`** Request **`@Body`** should be **`JSONObject`**

```
@POST("smsCheck")
    fun checkSMS(
        @Body json: JSONObject
    ) :Call<NetworkResult>
```

### FYI

For **`nameValuePairs`** issue You can use **JsonObject**.

> package com.google.gson;

```
JsonObject reqObject = new JsonObject();
        try{

            reqObject.addProperty("mobile","12345678");

        }
```

Add this in **`build.gradle`** section

```
implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6"
```

Comment: the result is same...""{\"mobile\":\"11111111\"}""

Comment: @Charles did you add `@Body json: JSONObject`

Comment: {"nameValuePairs":{"mobile":"11111111"}} I've got this result. nameValuePairs is not what I want... server have to remove this?

Comment: @Charles proced please

Comment: I tried changing 2.8.6 and using addProperty. but I can't find addProperty. jsonObject.addProperty()